# how to store a canvas image to mysql and retrieve it using nodejs

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I have a div and took a snapshot of that div using canvas and stored canvas image in a variable getcanvas, Now I want to store that canvas image to mysqldatabase using node

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways

- save image as dataUrl (i.e. a string).

```
 /* send */
 const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL()
 // TODO: post dataUrl to server and save it to mysql

 /* get */
 // get dataUrl from server
 const img = document.createElement('img');
 // attach dataUrl to img.src to show it
 img.src = dataUrl
```

- save canvas image as a real image

```
/* send */
const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL()
const [memeStr, dataStr] = (dataUrl || '').split(',')
const mime = memeStr
  .split(',')[0]
  .split(':')[1]
  .split(';')[0]

const bstr = atob(dataStr)
const u8arr = new Uint8Array(bstr.length)

for (let i = 0; i < bstr.length; i++) {
  u8arr[i] = bstr.charCodeAt(i)
}

const imageFile = new Blob([u8arr], { type: mime })
// TODO: you got the image file (by default is a png file)
// send it to the server and store its path in mysql

/* get */
// get imagePath from server
const img = document.createElement('img');
// attach imagePath to img.src to show it
img.src = imagePath
```